# Confusing imbrication of functions

Tags: calculus

I've encountered this question : Given that f, g, and h are differentiable functions, and f(g(h(x))) = x, what is h′(x) in terms of f, f′, g, g′ and h?

I am utterly confused. Could someone explain the thought process that should be involved in answering such a question?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the chain rule multiple times.
Since $f(g(h(x)))=x$, we can differentiate both side with respect to $x$ which gives $f'(g(h(x))) \cdot (g(h(x)))' = 1$ by the chain rule when we see $g(h(x))$ as one function.
To find the derivative of $g(h(x))$, we can once again use the chain rule.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't see how I should use the chain rule. How does it even come into play?

Comment: @ArthurRimbaud Is this enough to get you started?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. I got : h'(x) = 1/f'(g(h(x)))*g'(h(x))   Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I have another question: find the derivative of f(cos x), if f′(x) = 1/x. Is there some way to go from the derivative to the original function?

Comment: Yes, there is a way, but not needed in your second question. Try the chain rule on $f( \cos (x))$, and use the given $f'(x)$.